# Problem to detect diamond shape in box2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I make a simple game.

It has many diamond image and one ball. when ball touch with diamond shape then collision occur. in my application when ball touch on the edge then collision working correctly but when ball touch on the corner then collision is not working.

Code is hear..

```
- (id)init {

if ((self=[super init])) {

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    self.isAccelerometerEnabled=YES;
    // Create a world
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    bool doSleep = true;
    _world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);

    // Create edges around the entire screen
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
    _groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;
    b2FixtureDef groundBoxDef;
    groundBoxDef.shape = &groundBox;
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    _bottomFixture = _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);
    groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

    // Create sprite and add it to the layer
    CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball1.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16,16)];
   // ball.position = ccp(180, 400);
    ball.tag = 1;

// Create ball body 
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(180/PTM_RATIO, 450/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = ball;
     ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

    // Create circle shape
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 16/PTM_RATIO;
    //circle.m_radius = 50/PTM_RATIO;

    // Create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 0.0f; // We don't want the ball to have friction!
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    _ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);

    // Give shape initial impulse...
    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0, 0);
    ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBodyDef.position);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 


    {
        static int padding=25;



        CCSprite *block = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"diamond2.png"];
       int  xOffset = padding+block.contentSize.width/5+((block.contentSize.width+padding)*i);
        block.position = ccp(xOffset, 250);
        block.tag = 2;
        [self addChild:block];


        // Create block body
        b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
       // blockBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        blockBodyDef.position.Set(xOffset/PTM_RATIO, 400/PTM_RATIO);
        blockBodyDef.userData = block;

        b2Body *blockBody = _world->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);

        // Create block shape
        b2PolygonShape blockShape;
        blockShape.SetAsBox(block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/8,
                            block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/8
                            );

        // Create shape definition and add to body
        b2FixtureDef blockshapeDef;
        blockshapeDef.shape = &blockShape;
        blockshapeDef.density = 0.0;
        blockshapeDef.friction = 10.0;
        blockshapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
        blockBody->CreateFixture(&blockshapeDef);
    }

    [self addChild:ball]; 

// Create contact listener
    _contactListener = new MyContactListener();
    _world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background-music-aac.caf"];

    [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];

}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void)tick:(ccTime) dt {

   // bool blockFound = false;
_world->Step(dt, 10, 10);    
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {    
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();     



        if (sprite.tag == 1) {
            static int maxSpeed = 20;

            b2Vec2 velocity = b->GetLinearVelocity();
            float32 speed = velocity.Length();

            // When the ball is greater than max speed, slow it down by
            // applying linear damping.  This is better for the simulation
            // than raw adjustment of the velocity.
            if (speed > maxSpeed) {
                b->SetLinearDamping(0.2);
            } else if (speed < maxSpeed) {
                b->SetLinearDamping(0.0);
            }

        }

       sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        sprite.rotation = 1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());

}
}
}
```

Plz help me for detect correct collsion detection near corner of the diamond shape....

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. I'd recommend just posting the part that does collision detection.

Comment: I do comment for the specific code for your understand....

Comment: Try posting *just the lines of code that don't work* rather than 150 lines of code where we're supposed to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I don't see any comments pointing out what part of the code we should look at. You also need to define what you mean by 'not working'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understood but it seems you are not making a diamond, you are making a square/box:

```
blockShape.SetAsBox(block.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/8,block.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/8);
```

maybe that's why you're saying collision is not working.

If your body is a square and your sprite is a diamond there are three options:

- Or diamond has equal width and height and it's only **necessary to rotate the square**. Should be no problem with collision this way.
- Or other shapes collide on the (invisible)corner of square when is not supposed to be there (when sprite/diamond fits inside square and square has no rotation or diamond has width != height needing a customized shape)
- Or other shapes are not colliding with diamond sprite corner (when square is smaller and fits inside diamond sprite).

There are other methods to create customized shapes like:

```
void b2PolygonShape::Set(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 count)
void b2PolygonShape::SetAsEdge(const b2Vec2& v1, const b2Vec2& v2)
```